# How can I use YouTube API with JS to successfully carry out a search on my web page?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to carry out a YouTube search on a user-entered keyword in JS. Here is my code:

```js
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCzpZZP564ykVqpun38mS0AbtR0cHoEYE0');
}
 
function search() {
    var query = document.getElementById('query').value;
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q:query
    });
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

function onSearchResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = responseString;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/>
        <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
        <pre id="response"></pre>        
        <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error "TypeError: gapi.client is undefined". I haven't used YouTube API before so I would really appreciate any help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i found this [get started](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md) and accroding to this you have to run gapi.init()

Comment: Also you never call the onClientLoad method

Comment: I think the onClientLoad is called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded

Comment: Also how and where should I run gapi.init()? I'd really appreciate any help.